# Spring boot test: Wait for microservices schedulder task

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to test a service which's trying to communicate with other one.

One of them generates auditories which are stored on memory until an scheduled task flushs them on a redis node:

```
@Component
public class AuditFlushTask {

    private AuditService auditService;

    private AuditFlushTask(AuditService auditService) {
        this.auditService = auditService;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fo.audit-flush-interval}")
    public void flushAudits() {
        this.auditService.flush();
    }

}
```

By other hand, this service provide an endpoint stands for providing those flushed auditories:

```
public Collection<String> listAudits(
) {
    return this.boService.listRawAudits(deadlineTimestamp);
}
```

The problem is I'm building an integration test in order to check if this process works right, I mean, if audits are well provided.

So, I don't know how to "wait until audits has been flushed on microservice".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't test the framework: Spring almost certainly has tests which test fixed delays.

Instead, keep all logic within the service itself, and integration test that in isolation from the Spring `@Scheduled` function.